# make circular checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

using xml reading of contents of a particular thing i am adding checkboxes and its description.But the problem is that i want visual of my checkbox like radiobutton but it should work like checkbox.I mean i can check and uncheck it.Moreover on space of tick(in checkboxes),it should be dot(may be of any color if possible).

```
$(xml).find("Layer[Name='"+layerName+"']").find("IndustryComponent").each(function()
            {
                var layerDesciption= $(this).attr('Name');
                if($(this).is(':empty'))
                {
                    $(".InsideLayerContainer").append("<input type='checkbox' name='' value='' disabled='true'><label>"+layerDesciption+"</label><br/>");   
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".InsideLayerContainer").append("<input type='checkbox' name='' value=''><label>"+layerDesciption+"</label><br/>");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't really recommend it, but you can always make radio buttons work like checkboxes, if that's what you're really after ?

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
    this.checked = !$(this).data('checked')
    $(this).data('checked', !$(this).data('checked'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v52zD/1/)

Comment: you got me right..i more thing i want to give color to radio button and on mouse click its color should change and regain its color on another click and so on

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

Check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Xqr4n/2/

## HTML

```
<input class="myCheck" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">check 1<br />
<input class="myCheck" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">check 2<br />
<input class="myCheck" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">check 3<br />
```

## JQUERY

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<span class="circle">');
});

$('.circle').on("click", function(){
    if($(this).css("background-color") == 'rgb(223, 223, 223)') { 
        $(this).find('.myCheck').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).css({'background-color':'rgb(0, 64, 212)'});
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.myCheck').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).css({'background-color':'rgb(223, 223, 223)'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a image overlay for that.

Create two images one for unchecked view and one for checked view then based on the click value update a hidden checkbox and change the visible image also